PowerShell: How to find the right node with Namespacemanager in gpresult generated xml document?
I am currently trying to find a certain GPO by having its name by using SelectSingleNode.
Since the nodes in my xml document have namespaces such as q24:Name I am struggling.
XML looks like this:
<Rsop xmlns:xsd="URL" xmlns:xsi="URL" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Rsop">
<ReadTime>2024-03-20T13:45:23.8888739Z</ReadTime>
<DataType>LoggedData</DataType>
<UserResults>
...
</UserResults>
<ComputerResults>
...
<q24:Policy>
<GPO xmlns="URL">
<Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">{FC2D09DB-6814-4939-8971-8B459C5E9977}</Identifier>
<Domain xmlns="URL">officelan.izb</Domain>
</GPO>
<Precedence xmlns="URL">1</Precedence>
<q24:Name>Configure Drive Maps preference logging and tracing</q24:Name>
<q24:State>Enabled</q24:State>  

I want to find the Policy by its Name and return the state.
My code:
function Check-GPO {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$XmlPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$policyName,
        [string[]]$Namespaces = @("q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15", "q16", "q17", "q18", "q19", "q24")
    )

[xml]$xmlData = cat $xmlPath

$policyU = $xmlData.Rsop.UserResults.GPO | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $policyName }
#$policyPC = $xmlData.Rsop.ComputerResults.ExtensionData.Extension.Policy.GPO | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $policyName }

#namespacemanager
$nsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xmlData.NameTable)


foreach ($ns in $Namespaces) {
        $nsManager.AddNamespace($ns, "URL")
    }

$xpath = "//q24:Name[text()='$policyName']"#"//Policy[Name='$policyName']"
$policyPC = $xmlData.SelectSingleNode($xpath, $nsManager)
    
if ($policyU -or $policyPC) {
    if ($policyU.Link.Enabled -eq "true") {
    Write-Output "Die User-Gruppenrichtlinie '$policyName' ist aktiviert."
    } 
    elseif($policyPC.State -eq "Enabled") {
    Write-output "Die PC-Gruppenrichtlinie '$policyName' ist aktiviert."
    }
    else { Write-Output "Die Gruppenrichtlinie ist deaktiviert." }
}

else {
    Write-Output "Die Gruppenrichtlinie '$policyName' existiert nicht."
}
}


Thanks for any feedback.
P.S.: I exchanged all URLs with "URL" due to Stackoverflow flagging me question as spam.

You can use another predicate clause to target the nodes by local name alone: //*[local-name() = 'Name' and text()='$policyName']

It looks like you're already using PowerShell's dot notation ($xmlData.Rsop.UserResults.GPO | ...) - which is namespace-agnostic - to locate the elements of interest. Do you really need to use .SelectSingleNode() as well?

I use the dot notation to find the UserResults, since there aren't prefixes such as 'q24:'. I dont think the dot notation works if I don't know the exact path?

Nvm I managed to find ComputerResults as well. The only thing I'm missing is a correct output of the state or the SettingNumber. I am trying using .InnerText but the output is empty, what am I doing wrong?
